Please check my calculations for solution prep
I need to prepare a 10,000 ppm solution of 3-Pentanol. The final volume needs to be 500 mL. Here is what I came up with:

Calculate the mass of the solute needed: Mass of solute (mg) = (Desired ppm concentration) x (Volume of solution in mL) / 1,000,000.
(10,000 mg/L)(500 mL)/1,000,000 = 5.0 mg
Volume needed = mass of solute/(purity as decimal) (density in g/mL)
The 3-Pentanol I have is 98% pure, density = 0.815g/mL.
5.0mg/0.7987 = 6.26mL needed in 500mL.
I was taught that density must be included in the calculations when making solutions from liquid solutions. The method I was given uses weight only for making this solution from a liquid.
Thank you in advance!


ppm is ambiguous unit, if used without determination of what parts are counted. Also, you confused mg and g.

Thanks. Where did I confuse mg and g? I thought 10,000 mg/L = 10,000 ppm.

1 PPM is 1 mg/kg or 1 uL/L or 1 umol/mol. If there is default assumption of density 1kg/L,  then 1 ppm can be 1 mg/L. and 10000 ppm 10 g/L

One half of 10000 mg is not 5 mg. Volume of 5 mg is not 6.26 mL.

$$C_1V_1=C_2V_2\implies V_1=V_2\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)$$
$$\frac{C_2}{C_1}=\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)\left(\frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1}\right)$$
$$V_1=V_2\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)\left(\frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1}\right)\approx(\pu{500mL})\left(\frac{0.01}{0.98}\right)\left(\frac{\pu{1g/mL}}{\pu{0.815g/mL}}\right)\approx\pu{6.26mL}$$
It is not necessary to do mass and volume conversions because these will cancel out in the density ratio.

Thank you! So, was I correct in wanting to include density in the calculation? The person who wrote the method years ago simply added liquid by weight to the flask, after correcting for purity (like I would do for a solid).

@mrbackflush If both methods arrive at the same result, selection should be based on the readily available data. In this case, all variables are immediately known except for the final mass fraction which is easily calculated with: $y_2=10^{-6}\cdot [ppm]$
